# Foreach loop in Python to extract value from array in json response

Tags: python, powershell

I've got this json response:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "basic": {
            "bandwidth_class": "",
            "failure_pool": "",
            "max_connection_attempts": 0,
            "max_idle_connections_pernode": 50,
            "max_timed_out_connection_attempts": 2,
            "monitors": [
                "Simple HTTP"
            ],
            "node_close_with_rst": false,
            "node_connection_attempts": 3,
            "node_delete_behavior": "immediate",
            "node_drain_to_delete_timeout": 0,
            "nodes_table": [
                {
                    "node": "abc1.prod.local:80",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "state": "active",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "def1.prod.local:80",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "state": "disabled",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "ghi1.prod.local:80",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "state": "disabled",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "jkl1.prod.local:80",
                    "priority": 1,
                    "state": "active",
                    "weight": 1
                }
            ],
            "note": "",
            "passive_monitoring": true,
            "persistence_class": "",
            "transparent": false
        }
    }
}
```

And this powershell script:

```
$nodesAarray = "abc1.prod.local:80", "jkl1.prod.local:80"
foreach($node in $nodesArray)
{
    $nodes_match_and_enabled = $GetNodesResponse.properties.basic.nodes_table | Where { $_.node -eq $node -and $_.state -eq "active" }
    if($nodes_match_and_enabled)
    {
        Write-Output "$node exists in the pool and active"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Output "$node is either not active or the name mismatches"
        $global:invalidNodeArray.Add($node)     
    }
}
```

In my powershell script I am looping to check the two nodes in my array actually match by value and the state is active. It works as I expect.

However, I am scripting the same exact logic in Python (I am a beginner) but not sure how to approach it. Any idea what the script would look like in Python???

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming and will do! @wwii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, filter all active nodes, then compare with node list:

```
data = json.loads(text)
active_nodes = {
    n['node']
    for n in data['properties']['basic']['nodes_table']
    if n['state'] == 'active'
}

nodes = {"abc1.prod.local:80", "jkl1.prod.local:80"}
for node in nodes:
    if node in active_nodes:
        print('{} exists in the pool and active'.format(node))
    else:
        print('{} is either not active or the name mismatches'.format(node))

invalid_nodes = nodes - active_nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work in Python 2 or 3, I think:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json

res = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
  res += line.rstrip()

res_obj = json.loads(res)

nodes = [ 'abc1.prod.local:80', 'jkl1.prod.local:80' ]

invalid_nodes = []

for node in nodes:
  try:
    found = False
    test_node_objs = res_obj['properties']['basic']['nodes_table']
    for test_node_obj in test_node_objs:
      test_node = test_node_obj['node']
      if node == test_node:
        found = True
        break
    if found:
      sys.stdout.write("%s exists in the pool and active\n" % (node))
    else:
      sys.stdout.write("%s is either not active or the name mismatches\n" % (node))
      invalid_nodes.append(node)
  except KeyError as ke:
    sys.stderr.write("malformed response? check input...\n")
    pass
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./parse_response.py < response.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation:

```
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonSrc)

expectedNodes = {"abc1.prod.local:80", "jkl1.prod.local:80"} 

for node in expectedNodes:
    node_table = jsonObj['properties']['basic']['nodes_table']

    node_match = list(filter(lambda t_node: node == t_node['node'], node_table))
    is_node_matches_and_active = len(node_match) > 0 and node_match[0]['state'] == "active"
    if is_node_matches_and_active:
        print('node {} exists and is active'.format(node))
    else:
        print('node {} not found or not active'.format(node))
```

Output :

```
node jkl1.prod.local:80 exists and is active
node abc1.prod.local:80 exists and is active
```